Detect duplicate rows in excel across columns containing blanks
I am trying to decide if duplicate rows appears in a table in excel which also has some blank fields.
The countif formula isn't giving the desired result as it is not taking into account the blanks.
 A B C
 1   2  -duplicate
 0 1 2
 1   2  -duplicate
 1   

The formula given here does not work for me because I cannot use an extra column just a single cell which says if there are or not duplicates in the table.

How big is your table/data set?

What is your excel version?

@Blackcat Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise

@Excellor less than 500

Just to clarify, (because of an Answer I see below), is it your intent that <blank>|1|2, 1|<blank>|2 and 1|2|<blank> are all duplicates of each other, or unique?

@RonRosenfeld I need a single cell which says if there any duplicated rows in the table (there might be blank cells and I cannot use an extra column)

That doesn't answer my question.

@RonRosenfeld Sorry, I missunderstood you. The example you wrote are unique for me.

Transform to 365 the formula you have tried.
With BYROW and TEXTJOIN functions:
=LET(table,BYROW(A$1:C$4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,x))),
IF(SUM(IF(table=TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,A1:C1),1,0))>1,"duplicate",""))

in D1 cell and dragdown
The column displays the duplicated rows.
If you need only to detect the exist of any duplicates in the table apply this formula:
=LET(table,BYROW(A$82:C$84,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("|",FALSE,x))),
table2,BYROW(table,LAMBDA(xx,SUM(IF(xx=table,1,0))>1)),
IF(OR(table2),"duplicate",""))

This is a single cell with the text duplicate if there is any.

I cannot use an extra column just a single cell which says if there are or not duplicates in the table. With extra column it is easy.

Pls. find the improved version.

With 365 you can enter a single formula in some cell and it will fill-down the results.
In the formula below d represents the data range:
Formula is entered in E1 only
=LET(
    d, $A$1:$C$9,
    a, IF(
        MAKEARRAY(
            ROWS(d),
            1,
            LAMBDA(r, c,
                SUM(--BYROW(EXACT(CHOOSEROWS(d, r), d), LAMBDA(arr, AND(arr))))
            )
        ) > 1,
        "Duplicate",
        ""
    ),
    a
)


The portion of the formula that equates to
a1:c1 = a1:c4

will return an array of values determining whether the rows match.
AND(arr)

will return TRUE if all the elements in the row match.
So we can easily see if there is more than one row that matches, in which case the SUM will be more than one.
EDIT:
It appears you want your duplicate test in a single cell. As you did not show an example as to how you want it presented, one of the following modifications of my solution may be appropriate.

A simple TRUE/FALSE:
=OR(
    LET(
        d, $A$1:$C$4,
        a, MAKEARRAY(
            ROWS(d),
            1,
            LAMBDA(r, c, SUM(--BYROW(EXACT(CHOOSEROWS(d, r), d), LAMBDA(arr, AND(arr)))))
        ) > 1,
        a
    )
)



A Count:
=SUM(
    --LET(
        d, $A$1:$C$4,
        a, MAKEARRAY(
            ROWS(d),
            1,
            LAMBDA(r, c, SUM(--BYROW(EXACT(CHOOSEROWS(d, r), d), LAMBDA(arr, AND(arr)))))
        ) > 1,
        a
    )
) & " duplicate rows"


And you can easily modify the formula to obtain whatever output format you require.

@RonRosenfield I cannot use an extra column just a single cell which says if there are or not duplicates in the table. With extra column it is easy.

@IstvanHeckl See my edits

@RonRosnfeld Sorry I checked the answer of BlackCat first, it was correct and I ansered his answer. That is why I can only upvote your answer.

@IstvanHeckl didn't see that. No problem

Going back to the original idea of using Countifs, the reason this doesn't work
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1)>1,"duplicate","")

is that A1, B1 and C1 are being interpreted as zero when those cells are blank.
You can get round it by testing each of them:
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,IF(A1="","",A1),B:B,IF(B1="","",B1),C:C,IF(C1="","",C1))>1,"duplicate","")


This also means that completely blank rows count as duplicates.
More modern with spill formula and a dynamic range:
=BYROW(A.:.C,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,IF(INDEX(r,1)="","",INDEX(r,1)),B:B,IF(INDEX(r,2)="","",INDEX(r,2)),C:C,IF(INDEX(r,3)="","",INDEX(r,3)))>1,"duplicate","")))

But it would still mean that if you had a single completely blank row in the data it would count as a duplicate because of all the other blanks in A:A, B:B and C:C.
You would need something like this to detect duplicate blank rows within the data but not flag single blank rows:
=LET(nr,ROWS(A.:.C),BYROW(A.:.C,LAMBDA(r,IF(COUNTIFS(A1:INDEX(A:A,nr),IF(INDEX(r,1)="","",INDEX(r,1)),B1:INDEX(B:B,nr),IF(INDEX(r,2)="","",INDEX(r,2)),C1:INDEX(C:C,nr),IF(INDEX(r,3)="","",INDEX(r,3)))>1,"duplicate",""))))


To test for duplicates in a single cell, try
=IF(ROWS(A1:C4)<>ROWS(UNIQUE(A1:C4)),"duplicate","")

or using a dynamic range
=IF(ROWS(A.:.C)<>ROWS(UNIQUE(A.:.C)),"duplicate","")


Hi Tom, Sorry if I misslead you. I cannot use an extra column just a single cell which says if there are or not duplicates in the table. With extra column it is easy.

I've tried with my logic, I feel I've given all possibilities.
=IF(OR(SUM(--ISBLANK(A2:C2))=1,SUM(COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2:C2))>3),"duplicate","")



Hi Manoj, I cannot use an extra column just a single cell which says if there are or not duplicates in the table. Sorry if my image misslead you.

you can try this
=SUM(--(COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, B:B, B:B, C:C, C:C) > 1)) > 0

COUNTIFS(A:A, A:A, B:B, B:B, C:C, C:C):
Counts how many times each combination of A, B, and C values appears in
the table. Handles blanks because it explicitly matches them.


1:
Checks if any row combination appears more than once.


--(...):
Converts TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 for summing.
SUM(...) > 0:
Sums up the duplicates and returns TRUE if there are
duplicates or FALSE otherwise.

Note: This formula works for tables with columns A, B, and C. If you have more columns, extend the formula accordingly.

I already tried this and it does not handle the blanks.

=SUM(--(COUNTIFS(A:A, "<>", A:A, A:A, B:B, B:B, C:C, C:C) > 1)) > 0
please give it a try
